# Создание формы для вставки данных

Tags: php

Приветствую! Уважаемые Хешкодовцы, прошу Вас помочь мне ибо с PHP я столкнулся впервые)

Есть таблица в MySQL:

```
create table stack (id SMALLINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, ip CHAR(20) NOt NULL, type BOOLEAN NULL, PRIMARY KEY (id));
```

Прошу вас помочь мне написать форму для вставки данных через веб интерфейс на PHP.

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO  `jevi`.`stack` (`id` ,`ip` ,`type`)VALUES (NULL ,  '12313123',  '0');
```

это запрос в бд

ну в форме должны быть поле типа text и либо checkbox либо radiobox(2 значения).

Comment: спасибо за ответ! но трудность состоит в том что я совершенно не знаю php

Comment: смотри темы по подключению к БД, и запросы MySql. Да и вообще начни изучать php+mysql

Comment: >я совершенно не знаю php

А что мешает почитать самоучитель для начала?

Comment: ничего не мешает.. я его и изучаю. возник вопрос с проверкой checbox у меня почемуто не выводится что в базе данных в логическом поле стоит значение try

Comment: Ну а как ты это поле проверяешь?

Comment: ну исходя из опыта программирования в других языках по моему мнпению это так должно выглядить но не работает пачамуто

Comment: сделай 
var_dump($_REQUEST); и посмотри какие значения передаются тебе.

зы. Всё-таки с русским языком у тебя проблемы :) ("выглядеть", "почему то")

Answer (score 0):

```
function checkbox_verify($_name)
{
$result=0;
if (isset($_REQUEST[$_name]))
{ if ($_REQUEST[$_name]=='on') { $result=1; } else { $result=0; }
}
return $result;
}
```

Comment: var_dump($_REQUEST);и скинь сюда что выводится.

Comment: согласен) пишу быстро на клаве по этому не заморачиваюсь.